# Что означает (widthOK, duration)

Tags: javascript, height

Объясните, пожалуйста, что означают в данном скрипте свойства  heightOK и widthOK, а также откуда javascript знает, что duration - это скорость изменения картинки в миллисекундах (если в коде нигде это не расшифровано):

```
function func(name, width, height, duration, type) {
    var img = document.images.im,
        heightOk = 0,
        widthOk = 0;
    if (type == true) {
        if ((h < height) && (w < width)) {
            if (img.height < height) img.height++;
            else heightOk = 1;
            if (img.width < width) img.width++;
            else widthOk = 1;
        }
        if ((h > height) && (w > width)) {
            if (img.height > height) img.height--;
            else heightOk = 1;
            if (img.width > width) img.width--;
            else widthOk = 1;
        }
        if ((h > height) && (w < width)) {
            if (img.height > height) img.height--;
            else heightOk = 1;
            if (img.width < width) img.width++;
            else widthOk = 1;
        }
        if ((h < height) && (w > width)) {
            if (img.height < height) img.height++;
            else heightOk = 1;
            if (img.width > width) img.width--;
            else widthOk = 1;
        }
        if (heightOk + widthOk == 2) setTimeout(func, duration, name, width, height, duration, false);
        else setTimeout(func, duration, name, width, height, duration, true);
    } else if (type == false) {
        if ((h < height) && (w < width)) {
            if (img.height > h) img.height--;
            else heightOk = 1;
            if (img.width > w) img.width--;
            else widthOk = 1;
        }
        if ((h > height) && (w > width)) {
            if (img.height < h) img.height++;
            else heightOk = 1;
            if (img.width < w) img.width++;
            else widthOk = 1;
        }
        if ((h > height) && (w < width)) {
            if (img.height < h) img.height++;
            else heightOk = 1;
            if (img.width > w) img.width--;
            else widthOk = 1;
        }
        if ((h < height) && (w > width)) {
            if (img.height > h) img.height--;
            else heightOk = 1;
            if (img.width < w) img.width++;
            else widthOk = 1;
        }
        if (heightOk + widthOk != 2) setTimeout(func, duration, name, width, height, duration, false);
        else setTimeout(func, duration, name, width, height, duration, true);
    }
}
var h = document.images.im.height;
var w = document.images.im.width;
var width = Number(prompt("Ведите максимальную ширину"));
var height = Number(prompt("Ведите максимальную высоту"));
var duration = Number(prompt("Ведите milliseconds"));
func('i', width, height, duration, true);
```

Comment: Код не читабелен, используйте вставку кода или PasteBin

Answer (score 1):

`widthOk` и `heightOk` в данном случае работают как стоп-флаги. При значении, равном единице ширина-высота не меняется.

Задержку между циклами изменений автор реализовал через 
`setTimeout(func, duration, name, width, height, duration, true);`

Код хоть и работает, ИМХО, ужасен.

Cуть этого текста можно читать примерно так:

```
...
  if  ((h == height) && (w == width)) return; // выход из цикла
  (img.height < height) ? img.heigth++ : img.heigth--;
  (img.width  < width)  ? img.width++  : img.width--;
...
setTimeout...
```